ESP32 Multiple SCO connection Limit problem
I'm using the ESP32S module and btstack library using it to connect two devices a phone and a headset over Bluetooth.
The ESP32 act as a relay it connects to the phone as HFP unit and to the headset as a HFP audio gateway.
The ESP32 works well with some phones like Samsung Galaxy J7 but with other phones like Samsung A22 it doesn't work
When I have ACL connection to both of them the ESP32 and the Samsung A22 or iphone and the ESP32 with the headset, I try to open SCO connection. And I can only open one. When trying to open the second one, the controller will respond with HCI ERROR: 0x0A (ERROR_CODE_SYNCHRONOUS_CONNECTION_LIMIT_TO_A_DEVICE_EXCEEDED)
It doesn't matter which device I connect, the first one will succeed and second will respond with this.
When trying to open the second SCO from other device, it will also not allow.
I did CONFIG_BTDM_CONTROLLER_BR_EDR_MAX_SYNC_CONN=3
I am using the latest version of btstack with esp-idf 4.4.3 and tried also esp-idf 5.2.1
I am using the hfp_hf_demo and hf_ag_demo examples without doing any edits just compined both examples.
Thanks.
I tried with around 5 phones with the same heaset always the same behaviour 1 SCO connection only allowed at a time but some phones works flawlessy.
I am expecting the ESP32 to act as a relay and I should be able to intiate SCO connection with both the phone and headset.
